# Appending callback function result to specific div/place?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a JavaScript plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) which I'm calling this way:

```js
camera.getPicture(successCallback, errorCallback, options)
```

The problem is that when I fire it, it just appends a div with class `.cordova-camera-capture` on the bottom of the page.

Can I somehow tell the plugin where to put the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the example code from the github page of the "cordova-plugin-camera" plugin? There are good explanation examples you can find [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameragetpicture-errata) :

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
   var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
   image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```